# Copying a integer value from one integer into another

Tags: c++, c++11, random, integer, srand

A very quick question l have to ask why the following will not work. I am an early programmer hence the reason l am asking for help.

I am trying to copy the value of num1gen into the integer of ballno1 and outputting it.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>


using namespace std;

int main()

{
int ballno1 = 0;

srand(time(NULL));
int num1gen=(rand()%49+1);


ballno1 = ballno1 + num1gen;
cout<<ballno1<<" ";

}
```

Comment: "why the following will not work" What do you mean by "not work"? And why do you think it won't?

Comment: This code should work okay, but you need to initialize your random number generator first with srand(time(NULL))

Comment: @pelya There is `srand(time(NULL));` in the code already...

Comment: @Borgleader ballno1 should output the value of num1gen and it instead outputs '0'.

Comment: what compiler are you using?

Comment: @MikeEricson [It does exactly that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4fcce5c5ac6b0a7e), hence my question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To copy `num1gen` into `ballno1` use `ballno1 = num1gen;` - very simple.

PS: `num1gen` is not "integer" but "integer variable". Integer is the value.

Comment: But there was nothing wrong with the original code, even if it wasn't the most straight-forward way. How could this possibly be the answer?

Comment: The question was "copying one integer (variable) to another". And the original code is `ballno1 = ballno1 + num1gen`. With `ballno1` initialized to 0 the result looks the same but the integer is copyed correctly as side effect - if ballno1 has different value, the assignment will be incorrect.

Comment: The question was specifically why the code was always returning the same value `0`. This change shouldn't have affected the result from the posted code *at all*, so I'm mystified how the OP decided it was the answer. P.S. the downvotes aren't mine, I save those for answers that are totally incorrect - this one isn't.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and it seems that every time, the output of the rand function is congruent 3 with 49. You can get your expected result using the line:

```
int num1gen=((rand()%1000)%49+1);
```

Of course, you can choose any number, not exactly 1000.

Answer (score -1):

Two issues here. First is that `time(NULL)` doesn't change very often, or very much. If you're running the program over and over, don't expect it to change every time. Second, most implementations of `rand` are very correlated with the seed for the first one or two random numbers you pull from them. You should throw away the first couple of calls to `rand` that you use.

Or better yet, use the improved random number facilities built into C++11. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

Comment: This doesn't even remotely address the question.

Comment: @Wharbio that's because the question doesn't make sense - there's no way the posted code could generate the claimed output. This is an attempt to explain why you might see the same output when running this code multiple times, because that's what I gathered the real question was by reading between the lines.